# Heteroskedasticity that is not due to excluded moderating variables

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

Is heteroskedasticity always caused by excluded moderating variables in a regression model? Are there any phenomena where heteroskedasticity is independent from such exclusion?

Answer (score 0):

> Is heteroskedasticity always caused by excluded moderating variables in a regression model?

No.

> Are there any phenomena where heteroskedasticity is independent from such exclusion?

Yes. Heteroskedasticity may be due to entering as a multiplicative effect for example which would be expected to produce standard deviation proprotional to the mean.

Or consider count data, which sometimes has standard deviation approximately proportional to the square root of the mean.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, thank you for your answer. I am still a bit confused about the multiplicative effect. I don't think what you mean is interaction effect because it will be the same with entering the moderating variables. Can you give me an illustrative example?